# Cannot find symbol R class in Buck build when refer to a R.string.appname in example of Buck build

Tags: buck

Can anybody help me about buck build. When I build android project, and Activity have reference to R.java (getString(R.string.name)) then I cannot build. It always return cannot find symbol R class. Although when I build project which have Activity and string.xml no error and R.java also was generated in this case

Comment: What do your `BUCK` files look like?  You haven't really provided enough information to get help.

Comment: Also, is this the same as https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/476?